# probability proof derivation from axioms

Tags: probability-theory

I want to figure out how to derive the following proof from the following axioms. Please show the steps and explain each step cause I want to learn how it's done.

1. $P(E)≥0$
2. $P(Ω) = 1$
3. $P(E∪F)=P(E)+P(F)$ if $E∩F = \varnothing$

With these axioms, how can I derive the following?

$P(E ∩ F^c) = P(E) − P(E ∩ F)$

Comment: Well, what have you tried? This is a simple consequence of the third axiom.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(E\cap F)\cup(E\cap F^c)=E\cap(F\cup F^c)=E$, and $(E\cap F)\cup(E\cap F^c)=\emptyset$.

Then, by (3), $P(E)=P((E\cap F)\cup(E\cap F^c))=P(E\cap F)+P(E\cap F^c)$. Then $P(E\cap F^c)=P(E)-P(E\cap F)$.

Note that in general the argument fails for measures. Indeed, this argument is valid for finite measures. In particular for probability measures.